# Как нажать на кнопку в Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

есть код:

```
baseurl = 'https://cs.money/ru/csgo/store/?search=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29&sort=price&order=asc&minFloat=0.2813&maxFloat=0.4438

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(baseurl)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button').click()`
```

но на кнопку он не нажимает [image: вот это обявление]
вот кнопка
[image: кнопка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда известно, что не нажимает

Comment: @Эникейщик тем что ошибка в консоли и то что на сайте висит кнопка

Comment: И что же написано в ошибке?

Comment: @Эникейщик то что кнопка не найдена. Или я что-то не понимаю? Если я вдруг говорю что-то неправильно то объясни пж.

Comment: Значит, проблема не в том, что кнопка не нажимается, а в том, что она не находится.

Comment: @Эникейщик да но когда заходишь в исследовать код и ПКМ нажимаешь скопировать xpath то выходит то что в коде

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте, у меня работает ваш код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


baseurl = 'https://cs.money/ru/csgo/store/?search=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29&sort=price&order=asc&minFloat=0.2813&maxFloat=0.4438'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(baseurl)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button').click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="modal"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button"}

Comment: у меня вот такая ошибка

Comment: @Marlin09 у меня тоже сработал этот код без проблем. Вы уверены, что выполняете данный скрипт без добавления доп. кода?

Comment: хм... у меня просто закрывается веб драйвер и в консоле ошибка то что элемент не найден. Нет это единственный скрипт больше в коде нет нечего

Comment: @FedorMarch вот смотри я отредактировал вопрос ошибка остается

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего (надеюсь на это), страница не успевает загрузится (довольно много содержимого) перед выполнением команды
`driver.find_element().click()`

Предлагаю, добавить ожидание:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


baseurl = 'https://cs.money/ru/csgo/store/?search=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29&sort=price&order=asc&minFloat=0.2813&maxFloat=0.4438'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(baseurl)
time.sleep(15) #Ждем 15сек за это время страница должна загрузится
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button').click()
```

Можно попробовать увеличить время ожидания, если не загрузится

Comment: нет это тоже не помогает